# TypeError: gustavoCoinInstance.transferOwnership is not a function

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

I am getting the following error -
[image: Here is a error screenshot]

**GustavoCoin.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

import "../node_modules/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/MintableToken.sol";

contract GustavoCoin  {

    string public name = "GUSTAVO COIN";

    string public symbol = "GUS";

    uint8 public decimals = 18;
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

**GustavoCoinCrowdsale.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

import './GustavoCoin.sol';

import '../node_modules/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/emission/MintedCrowdsale.sol';

import '../node_modules/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/validation/TimedCrowdsale.sol';
contract GustavoCoinCrowdsale is TimedCrowdsale, MintedCrowdsale {

    function GustavoCoinCrowdsale

        (

            uint256 _openingTime,

            uint256 _closingTime,

            uint256 _rate,

            address _wallet,

            MintableToken _token

        )

        public

        Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token)

        TimedCrowdsale(_openingTime, _closingTime) {



        }
}
```

**truffle.js**

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
      development: {
          host: "127.0.0.1", 
          port: 8545, 
          network_id: "*" // Match any network id 
      } 
  }
};
```

I am follwimg a tutorial from [this](https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/how-to-create-token-and-initial-coin-offering-contracts-using-truffle-openzeppelin-1b7a5dae99b6) link.

Comment: Please provide the section of code which are relevant to your question - for example the truffle script is missing. Furthermore, your `GustavoCoin` does not have such function `transferOwnership`.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen I have also mentioned link which i'm following! GustavoCoin is a contract name and the given code is related to my question! for more clearance please see the link given there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [gist](https://gist.github.com/gustavoguimaraes/0810284f77d27c58331ba35e4ee8fb48#file-gustavocoin-sol) used by the tutorial you mentioned defines the contract as

```
pragma solidity 0.4.19;
import 'zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/MintableToken.sol';

contract GustavoCoin is MintableToken {
   ...
}
```

`MintableToken` inherits OpenZeppelin's `Ownable`, and that's where `transferOwnership` method can be found. Your code above lacks `is MintableToken` inheritance.

Comment: Then what we can do to resolve it? @Utgarda

Comment: Compare the contract definition line in your code with the gist, make your code look like the example. I.e. add `is MintableToken` after your contract name.